# Chanterelle and Chantrelle, which is the correct name of the mushroom?

Tags: etymology, orthography, writing-style, is-it-a-word, historical-change

I always spell it as chanterelle until I bought a box of CHANTRELLE in Whole Foods Market. I looked up my dictionary, and yes, the word should be chanterelle. However, I also noticed that, the word has three syllables as "chan-te-relle", while most of people pronounce it as "chan-trelle" with only two syllables. Some online resources ([link](https://www.wildernesscollege.com/chantrelle-mushrooms.html)) also claim that the two spellings are both correct.

I'm so confused. May anyone tell me which one is correct? Is the spelling CHANTRELLE in Whole Foods market also acceptable?

Comment: It's originally a French word, and in modern French, it has two syllables, but is spelled *chanterelle*.

Comment: What do you mean by “correct”?

Comment: @tchrist My question is that I saw a different spelling of the word in Whole Foods market which is different from what I learned in dictionary. So I would like to know if it is a wrong spelling or misuse or an acceptable variation?

Comment: @PeterShor I agree with you. But the mushroom box in Whole Foods market prints **CHANTRELLE** which makes me confused.

Comment: Yes. Three orthographic forms are found: chanterelle, from the 1700s on; chantarelle from the 1800s on, chantrelle, from the 1900s on. Whole Foods will spell it however they like, even if chantrelle is not the most frequent spelling.

Comment: @JEL May I know where did you find the information?

Comment: OED, but something like thefreedictionary.com might get you there. Dictionaries usually (but not always) put the most common spelling first. Using the most common spelling has advantages, but I doubt they're meaningful at Whole Foods.

Comment: @JEL Thanks. I did come from thefreedictionary.com :) It doesn't have chantrelle, and that's the reason I came here to ask.

Comment: There's a lot of snottiness about 'correct' spellings flying around ELU. 'Chantrelle' hasn't much general acceptance or currency, but it's not like spelling 'cat' as 'dog', for example. You knew what was meant, and that's really all it takes to communicate, although communicating as well as possible is another story.

Comment: Markets are quite relaxed about spellings. I would go with the dictionary. I've just looked at seven or eight famous ones online and they don't mention "chantrelle". One of the first examples of "chantrelle" I found on Google said they were seen on sale "**outside a french grogery store.**"

Comment: The people who program label-printing or box-printing machines are seldom English majors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Google Ngram search of the Google Books database](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chantarelle%2C+chanterelle%2C+chantrelle&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchantarelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchanterelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchantrelle%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cchantarelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchanterelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchantrelle%3B%2Cc0) for the period 1800–2019 shows that *chanterelle* (red line) is much the preferred spelling today over *chantarelle* (blue line) and *chantrelle* (green line)—and has been for some time:

[image]

The preference for *chanterelle* is actually stronger in published writing than these line plots might suggest because many of the recent matches for *chantarelle* and *chantrelle* don't involve mushrooms at all, whereas the vast majority of matches for *chanterelle* do.

The dominance of *chanterelle* over the other two spellings (at least in U.S. English) is confirmed by the entries for *chanterelle* in both *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) and *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010): neither dictionary lists any variant spelling for the word, suggesting that the lexicographers behind these dictionaries think that *chantarelle* and *chantrelle* have minimal followings today.

Correct spelling is ultimately a popularity contest, however, not  matter of divine right. So if Whole Foods persists in its orthographical preference and manages to draw other influential publishers to its side, we may eventually see *chanterelle/chantrelle* go the way of [*catsup/ketchup*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catsup%2Cketchup&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Comment: More on the history of _catsup/ketchup_ [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36633/why-do-catsup-and-ketchup-coexist).